# I've changed region for AWS EC2 instance. But I can't see a website from new IP address and Public DNS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I've made a change regions for one of AWS EC2 instances from U.S. Virginia to EU Frankfurt with AMI and snapshot.

But the new instance, EU Frankfurt is not displaying a website with Public DNS and IPv4 Public IP through the browser.
Is it because I haven't yet stopped an old instance, the one U.S. Virginia?
Both are WordPress (bitnami) website instances though I can't access admin login page neither with a new instance IP address and Public DNS.

While I searched, I thought about might need to relate EIP from Elastic IPs for a new instance. But I didn't relate EIP to my old instance then I assume setting EIP is not a solution for a problem I have mentioned in above.

There will be a retirement for my old instance in few days.
I need to solve this issue before AWS retire my old instance.
Is there anyone know a solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like WordPress isn't running on your new bitnami instance in EU Frankfurt. Per the [bitnami documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-start-or-stop-the-services):

Check current status of services:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
```

If they aren't running, start services:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

If they were running, maybe check to verify that you can access the application from within the instance, or maybe via the private IP. You may also try [changing the WordPress Domain Name](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-change-the-wordpress-domain-name) if you had configured that for the previous location.

If this behavior differs from the instance that is being retired (for example, if WordPress always restarted on its own after a system reboot) I would additionally check the old instance to make sure that it didn't have any [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data) that didn't get carried over to the new instance. That said, user data should be the only config missing -- other config like startup scripts on disk would have been maintained and carried over as part of the AMI. Your two instances are otherwise distinct.

### Further Reading

[Bitnami - First Steps With The Bitnami WordPress Stack](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#first-steps-with-the-bitnami-wordpress-stack) - This section contains instructions and default credentials for SSHing into the instance for different configurations.

Comment: Hi, Anthony. I tried to check a current status of services with AWS CLI but somehow, the command `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start` gave me a response just `sudo: /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh: command not found` . 


But I assume my new bitnami instance in EU Frankfurt is not running although I see on a console it's running.


Do you know why the command in above responds me back just an error...?

Comment: @shabibi You won't be able to check on your applications with the AWS CLI, you need to SSH into your EC2 instance to run those commands and check on your application. If the EC2 console says your instance is running, that means that the instance that your application would run on is available, but does not necessarily mean that your application is running. The EC2 console describes your infrastructure, not your application.

Comment: Hi, Anthony. I tried to set up a same security group settings from my previous instance. It perfectly worked and now I can access a new instance WordPress as well as all data looks copied successfully. Your advice was really details and it helped me to figure out. Thanks a lot!